# Snowflake support for WKT M values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, esri

We are beginning to place a fair amount of our spatial data in Snowflake. Linear data that has M - measure data does not appear to be supported in Snowflake, even though it is part of the OGC spec. When we attempt to import data with M (e.g. (X Y Z M)) values Snowflake currently throws an error. Has anyone had experience with this, or know of a useful workaround? We really don't want to lose our measure values.

Comment: Please update your question with a minimal reproducible example: the ddl for a table, the insert statement to load data into that table and the full error message that you get